# Android ListView: how to avoid database query in bindView()? Need to fetch one to many relationship data

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite, android-cursor, android-cursorloader

I have a list view to display albums. In each album list item, I need to display some information from each photo in this album. Here is how my cursor loader looks like:

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return new CursorLoader(this, AlbumsColumns.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    long albumId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(AlbumsColumns._ID));

    Cursor photoCursor = getContentResolver().query(PhotosColumns.CONTENT_URI, null, PhotosColumns.ALBUM_ID + " = ?", 
            new String[]{Long.toString(albumId)}, null);

    if (photoCursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{

            // Here I collect the information from each photo in the album

        }while(photoCursor.moveToNext());
    }

    photoCursor.close();
}
```

Basically, I let the cursor loader manage the album query, and each time in the bindView I query the photos from the passed in album cursor. I feel this can be a performance issue. Is there a better way doing this?

Comment: One solution would be to have a custom loader that performs all of these queries in the background thread and returns a list of objects containing the info you need.

Comment: @dymmeh Yeah, I just realized this should be the right way.

Comment: BTW, performance is one thing. There's a potential bug, all the photos updates won't be notify if I did query by myself in bingView()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got an idea: use another cursor loader inside the list item. So this will be like two level cursor loader. I'll post my results later.

**Edit**:

The proposed idea should be the right way handling the issue. So my code is refactored like this:

```
// In the list view activity:

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        AlbumListItem albumListItem = (AlbumListItem)view;

        albumListItem.prepareView(getLoaderManager(), cursor);
    }

// AlbumListItem is a class that has a cursor loader to query photos:
public class AlbumListItem extends RelativeLayout implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{


public void prepareView(LoaderManager loaderManager, Cursor albumCursor){

    albumId = albumCursor.getLong(albumCursor.getColumnIndex(AlbumsColumns._ID));
    // Other init stuff

    loaderManager.initLoader(UNIQUE_LOADER_ID, null, this);
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

    // Here is the async query part.

    return new CursorLoader(context, PhotosColumns.CONTENT_URI, null, PhotosColumns.ALBUM_ID + " = ?", new String[]{Long.toString(albumId)}, null);
}

}
```