# Get ALBUM_ART from song

Tags: android

First of all I should say I'm new to Android programming...
I'm retrieving all my songs in my phone and displaying in a ListView using LoadManager and BindView to display the data. But I cannot get the ALBUM_ART showing in my ImageView.

This is exactly what I need...

[Android ListView: how to avoid database query in bindView()? Need to fetch one to many relationship data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21144964/android-listview-how-to-avoid-database-query-in-bindview-need-to-fetch-one-t)

but I don't know how to implement it.

My BindView from songs loadermanager

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context contex, Cursor cursor) {

TextView songText = (TextView) view.getTag(R.id.txt_title);
TextView artistText = (TextView) view.getTag(R.id.txt_artist);
ImageView albumImg = (ImageView) view.getTag(R.id.img_album);

albumId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));
```

and my other other LoaderManager that I'd like to call inside my bindView to retrieve the album_art

```
public class AlbumListItem implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

        String[]  projection =  {
                MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID,
                MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART,
     };


        return new CursorLoader(MainActivity.this, MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection
                , MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ID + " = ?", new String[]{albumId}, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

But as I said I don't know how to (or where) insert or initialise AlbumListItem loader
getLoaderManager().initLoader(ID, null, MainActivity.this);

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar program and the source code is at https://github.com/pbirdsall/jasonisframed.  Feel free to look at and see if it helps.  I basically pull text and images, load them into a database and put them into a listview.